# Using apt to install mysql, the "additional disk space to be used" is 10x bigger than the size of needed archives. How?

Tags: apt

I've seen this before with other apps, but tonight I noticed it with mysql:

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server
[...]
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 161 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Compression can't account for anywhere near that kind of difference, can it?

Comment: It may need to be using additional temporary space during installation and/or the compressed archive is actually really _well_ compressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mariadb-client-10.1`, one of the packages that will be installed by that command, [is 5,704kiB](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/mariadb-client-10.1) (on amd64). It installs to 45,347kiB, roughly eight times the size, and pretty much in line with the 18.7/161 ratio you see.

Let's extract the files and see where that comes from:

```
$ ar x mariadb-client-10.1_10.1.26-0+deb9u1_amd64.deb
$ tar xJf data.tar.xz
$ du -shc usr/bin usr/share etc
45M     usr/bin
200K    usr/share
20K     etc
45M     total
```

So we can see that the package does extract to very close to the posted size. All we've done is use standard extraction tools, so there's nothing unusual `apt` is doing.

We can look a little closer:

```
$ du -s usr/bin/mariabackup
18M     usr/bin/mariabackup
$ xz < usr/bin/mariabackup|wc -c
4542540
```

So we can see that *a single file* is three times the size of the package and compresses down to smaller than the package with no special effort. Others compress even better, and compressed tar files are able to exploit further redundancy across multiple contained files.

So, yes, compression accounts for everywhere near that difference.

Answer (score 2):

That is *all* down to compression. See for example [the `mariadb-server-10.1` package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/mariadb-server-10.1) which contains 76,605 kB of files on `amd64` but compresses down to 
5,208.2 kB...

Bear in mind that the compression used here is `xz` over an entire tarball, so redundancy between files can be used to reduce the overall size. Many of the binaries shipped in the package have common sections. As [Michael Homer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/73093/michael-homer)’s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423759/86440) shows, even individual binaries compress very well.

The information used to present the sizes before installation is, on the one hand, the value given in [the “Installed-Size” field](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#s-f-installed-size) in the package meta-data, which is measured when the package is built, and gives a good indication of the actual size of the packages’ contents, and on the other hand, the size of the downloaded archive. The installed size doesn’t make any attempt to account for temporary disk space used during the installation, it only reflects the sizes of the files that are contained in the package.